# iframe doesn't show its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have created an iframe per dropdown.
So here is the html, css and JS:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#klanten-lijst').on('change',function(){
    $('#klanten div').hide();
    $('.klant-'+this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.styled-select {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   height: 45px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 500px;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 45px;
   padding: 5px; /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
   width: 520px;
}

.styled-select.slate {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2e3ybe1.jpg) no-repeat right center;
   height: 45px;
   width: 500px;
}

.styled-select.slate select {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 45px;
   width: 520px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0px 20px">Klanten</h2>
 <div class="styled-select slate" style="position:fixed;margin-left:20px;">
   <select name="klanten" id="klanten-lijst">
     <option>Klanten<option>
  <option value="1">7LAB LLP</option>
  <option value="2">A.Tuin Den Helder B.V.</option>
  <option id="option3" value="3">Ace Accounting</option>
  <option id="option4" value="4">Administratiekantoor A.C. Koenen</option>
  <option id="option5" value="5">Advocatenkantoor Roos</option>
  <option id="option6" value="6">Afix</option>
  <option id="option7" value="7">Agratechniek</option>
  <option id="option8" value="8">Anne van Dalen</option>
  <option id="option9" value="9">App-vise</option>
  <option id="option10" value="10">Arlette Hazevoet</option>
  <option id="option11" value="11">Asko Schoonmaak- en Bedrijfsdiensten B.V.</option>
  <option id="option12" value="12">ATAL B.V.</option>
  <option id="option13" value="13">Australian Backpackers B.V.</option>
  <option id="option14" value="14">Blommestein Gevelonderhoud</option>
  <option id="option15" value="15">Blooming bedrijvengroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option16" value="16">Borst Bedden B.V.</option>
  <option id="option17" value="17">Bouwbedrijf J. Nat. & Zn. B.V.</option>
  <option id="option18" value="18">BouwBoxr B.V.</option>
  <option id="option19" value="19">Broersma & De Boer Bouwadviesgroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option20" value="20">Bruin Assurantiën</option>
  <option id="option21" value="21">Bureau Gras</option>
  <option id="option22" value="22">Bureau4 V.O.F. </option>
  <option id="option23" value="23">Business Center Bonne Chance B.V.</option>
  <option id="option24" value="24">C.B.M. Poland</option>
  <option id="option25" value="25">CaseWare Nederland B.V.</option>
  <option id="option26" value="26">ColorCrew</option>
  <option value="27">Coos</option>
  <option value="28">Coperatieve Dienstverlening Heerhugowaard U.A.</option>
  <option value="29"></option>
  <option value="30"></option>
  <option value="31"></option>
  <option value="32"></option>
  <option value="33"></option>
   </select>
   
 <div id="klanten">
  <div class="klant-1" hidden>
   <iframe src="../klanten/7LAB LLP.html" style="height:410px;width:1880px;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="klant-2" hidden>
   <iframe src="../paginas/home.html" style="height:410px;width:1880px;"></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="../scripts/klant-reveal.js"></script>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why it isn't working and I have been breaking my brain over this for a little while now.

Its funny because when I change "hidden" by hand to "show" in F12 on the site it does show the frame with the mouse, but not the content itself.
Soo I have no clue where it could go wrong!

Thanks in advance,
Roel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use hidden attribute, if so then try removing the attribute. 
JQuery .show() changes css display to block or inline-block according to the element used.
So, either remove hidden attribute from the element using jQuery or
don't use hidden attribute instead do display:none on all the elements in css, so it will be hidden  until selection is done. On selection, use jquery.show()

For reference:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#klanten-lijst').on('change', function() {
    $('#klanten div').hide();
    $('.klant-' + this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.styled-select {
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 5px;
  /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
  width: 520px;
}

.styled-select.slate {
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2e3ybe1.jpg) no-repeat right center;
  height: 45px;
  width: 500px;
}

.styled-select.slate select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 520px;
}

#klanten {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#klanten div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0px 20px">Klanten</h2>
  <div class="styled-select slate" style="position:fixed;margin-left:20px;">
    <select name="klanten" id="klanten-lijst">
    <option>Klanten</option>
  <option value="1">7LAB LLP</option>
  <option value="2">A.Tuin Den Helder B.V.</option>
  <option id="option3" value="3">Ace Accounting</option>
  <option id="option4" value="4">Administratiekantoor A.C. Koenen</option>
  <option id="option5" value="5">Advocatenkantoor Roos</option>
  <option id="option6" value="6">Afix</option>
  <option id="option7" value="7">Agratechniek</option>
  <option id="option8" value="8">Anne van Dalen</option>
  <option id="option9" value="9">App-vise</option>
  <option id="option10" value="10">Arlette Hazevoet</option>
  <option id="option11" value="11">Asko Schoonmaak- en Bedrijfsdiensten B.V.</option>
  <option id="option12" value="12">ATAL B.V.</option>
  <option id="option13" value="13">Australian Backpackers B.V.</option>
  <option id="option14" value="14">Blommestein Gevelonderhoud</option>
  <option id="option15" value="15">Blooming bedrijvengroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option16" value="16">Borst Bedden B.V.</option>
  <option id="option17" value="17">Bouwbedrijf J. Nat. & Zn. B.V.</option>
  <option id="option18" value="18">BouwBoxr B.V.</option>
  <option id="option19" value="19">Broersma & De Boer Bouwadviesgroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option20" value="20">Bruin Assurantiën</option>
  <option id="option21" value="21">Bureau Gras</option>
  <option id="option22" value="22">Bureau4 V.O.F. </option>
  <option id="option23" value="23">Business Center Bonne Chance B.V.</option>
  <option id="option24" value="24">C.B.M. Poland</option>
  <option id="option25" value="25">CaseWare Nederland B.V.</option>
  <option id="option26" value="26">ColorCrew</option>
  <option value="27">Coos</option>
  <option value="28">Coperatieve Dienstverlening Heerhugowaard U.A.</option>
  <option value="29"></option>
  <option value="30"></option>
  <option value="31"></option>
  <option value="32"></option>
  <option value="33"></option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div id="klanten">
    <div class="klant-1">
      <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/q20yjtrh/2/" style="height:200px;width:500px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="klant-2">
      <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/q20yjtrh/2/" style="height:200px;width:500px;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't import the jquery library to your html,'$' can't do anything.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#klanten-lijst').on('change',function(){
    //$('#klanten div').hide();
    //$('.klant-'+this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.styled-select {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   height: 45px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 500px;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 45px;
   padding: 5px; /* If you add too much padding here, the options won't show in IE */
   width: 520px;
}

.styled-select.slate {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2e3ybe1.jpg) no-repeat right center;
   height: 45px;
   width: 500px;
}

.styled-select.slate select {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 45px;
   width: 520px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <h2 style="margin: 0 0 0px 20px">Klanten</h2>
 <div class="styled-select slate" style="position:fixed;margin-left:20px;">
   <select name="klanten" id="klanten-lijst">
     <option>Klanten<option>
  <option value="1">7LAB LLP</option>
  <option value="2">A.Tuin Den Helder B.V.</option>
  <option id="option3" value="3">Ace Accounting</option>
  <option id="option4" value="4">Administratiekantoor A.C. Koenen</option>
  <option id="option5" value="5">Advocatenkantoor Roos</option>
  <option id="option6" value="6">Afix</option>
  <option id="option7" value="7">Agratechniek</option>
  <option id="option8" value="8">Anne van Dalen</option>
  <option id="option9" value="9">App-vise</option>
  <option id="option10" value="10">Arlette Hazevoet</option>
  <option id="option11" value="11">Asko Schoonmaak- en Bedrijfsdiensten B.V.</option>
  <option id="option12" value="12">ATAL B.V.</option>
  <option id="option13" value="13">Australian Backpackers B.V.</option>
  <option id="option14" value="14">Blommestein Gevelonderhoud</option>
  <option id="option15" value="15">Blooming bedrijvengroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option16" value="16">Borst Bedden B.V.</option>
  <option id="option17" value="17">Bouwbedrijf J. Nat. & Zn. B.V.</option>
  <option id="option18" value="18">BouwBoxr B.V.</option>
  <option id="option19" value="19">Broersma & De Boer Bouwadviesgroep B.V.</option>
  <option id="option20" value="20">Bruin Assurantiën</option>
  <option id="option21" value="21">Bureau Gras</option>
  <option id="option22" value="22">Bureau4 V.O.F. </option>
  <option id="option23" value="23">Business Center Bonne Chance B.V.</option>
  <option id="option24" value="24">C.B.M. Poland</option>
  <option id="option25" value="25">CaseWare Nederland B.V.</option>
  <option id="option26" value="26">ColorCrew</option>
  <option value="27">Coos</option>
  <option value="28">Coperatieve Dienstverlening Heerhugowaard U.A.</option>
  <option value="29"></option>
  <option value="30"></option>
  <option value="31"></option>
  <option value="32"></option>
  <option value="33"></option>
   </select>
   
 <div id="klanten">
  <div class="klant-1" hidden>
   <iframe src="../klanten/7LAB LLP.html" style="height:410px;width:1880px;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="klant-2" hidden>
   <iframe src="../paginas/home.html" style="height:410px;width:1880px;"></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="../scripts/klant-reveal.js"></script>
 
 </div>
</div>
```